# Boundary of merged parcel feature does not disappear after merge

Tags: qgis, editing, merge, parcel, boundaries

In QGIS, when I merge several parcel features using Merge Selected Features, some of the boundary of parcels still remains.

---

Steps I used:

1. Enabled snapping options.
2. Enabled Toggle Editing.
3. Select Add Feature.
4. Created some parcel features.
5. Clicked on Save Layer Edits.
6. Goto View>Select>Select Feature(s).
7. Selected multiple parcel features that I created.
8. Selected Merge Selected Features.

Now when I save the merge, some boundary still remains.

---

I am using QGIS version 2.18.4

---

Some images:

[image: Created Parcel Features]
i. Created parcel features with snapping options enabled.

[image: Selected parcel features for merge]
ii. Selected parcel features for merge.

[image: Boundary still remains after merge]
iii. Boundary still remains after merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are gaps between the parcels. If you zoom in more closely, you will find gaps between the parcels, and in this case merge tool will not eliminate them.

You need to delete the gaps manually using the foolowing steps  after

1. Enable the edit mode and then.
2. Select the `Node tool` (see image below)

[image]

3. Select the vertex (node) and press on the delete button on your keyboard to delete the vertex

Also, you can try the `Delete Ring tool` (see image below) which enables you to delete the whole gap instead of selecting each vertex.

[image]